# Are there any security problems within my CentOS system?

Tags: linux, security, centos, port, nmap

I have tried to use [Nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) to test the ports of my server:) The details are as follows.

Are there some vulnerable ports on my server? If yes, why is it vulnerable, and
what should I do in order to protect my system?

Is there any better alternative software which can provide the same feature, or must I close that port?

```
nmap -A -T4 xxx.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-08-24 01:46 CST
Interesting ports on xxx.xxx:
Not shown: 979 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE        VERSION
21/tcp   open     ftp            PureFTPd
|_ ftp-anon: Anonymous FTP login allowed
22/tcp   open     ssh            OpenSSH 4.3 (protocol 2.0)
|  ssh-hostkey: 1024 f4:96:78:13:12:21:e2:e0:aa:88:ac:00:d8:aa:1b:6f (DSA)
|_ 2048 15:f1:4e:73:b4:e4:b1:04:d1:01:a4:2c:3d:52:35:71 (RSA)
25/tcp   open     smtp           netqmail smtpd 1.04
|  smtp-commands: EHLO xxx.xxx - Welcome to Qmail, STARTTLS, PIPELINING, 8BITMIME, SIZE 20971520, AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
|_ HELP netqmail home page: http://qmail.org/netqmail
53/tcp   open     domain
80/tcp   open     http           Apache httpd 2.2.22 ((CentOS))
|_ html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html; charset=UTF-8).
110/tcp  open     pop3           Courier pop3d
|_ pop3-capabilities: USER IMPLEMENTATION(Courier Mail Server) UIDL PIPELINING LOGIN-DELAY(10) TOP
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open     imap           Courier Imapd (released 2005)
|_ imap-capabilities: THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT QUOTA THREAD=REFERENCES UIDPLUS SORT IMAP4rev1 IDLE NAMESPACE CHILDREN
443/tcp  open     ssl/http       Apache httpd 2.2.22 ((CentOS))
|_ sslv2: server still supports SSLv2
|_ html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html; charset=UTF-8).
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
593/tcp  filtered http-rpc-epmap
801/tcp  open     http           nginx web server 1.3.5
|_ html-title: Welcome to nginx!
993/tcp  open     ssl/imap       Courier Imapd (released 2005)
|_ sslv2: server still supports SSLv2
|_ imap-capabilities: IMAP4rev1
995/tcp  open     ssl/pop3       Courier pop3d
|_ pop3-capabilities: USER IMPLEMENTATION(Courier Mail Server) UIDL PIPELINING LOGIN-DELAY(10) TOP
|_ sslv2: server still supports SSLv2
1434/tcp filtered ms-sql-m
2000/tcp open     http           Apache httpd 2.4.2 ((Unix))
|_ html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
3000/tcp open     ntop-http      Ntop web interface 3.3.9
3306/tcp open     mysql          MySQL 5.0.95
|  mysql-info: Protocol: 10
|  Version: 5.0.95
|  Thread ID: 1942
|  Some Capabilities: Connect with DB, Compress, Transactions, Secure Connection
|  Status: Autocommit
|_ Salt: jzF0ZU|3&a71/7g#uF>B
7777/tcp open     ssl/http       lighttpd 1.4.29
|_ html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html; charset=utf-8).
7778/tcp open     http           lighttpd 1.4.29
|_ html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html; charset=utf-8).
Service Info: OSs: Unix, Linux

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 52.62 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ran nmap from outside your LAN that would be very worrying.

Within a well-secured LAN somewhat less worrying.

You are running a lot of services, in particular of lot of different HTTP servers. nmap has been able to identify products and versions, this makes it easier for people to look up vulnerabilities specific to those products and versions I guess.

Do you need MySQL to be visible to other computers in the LAN?

Do you really need POP3 and IMAP and Webmail?

Could you replace FTP with SFTP?

Could you filter some of these services (restrict which source IP-addresses they will respond to)?